# Are there situations where an svg:text element's dominant-baseline is ignored?

Tags: svg

Are there situations where an SVG `<text>` element's `dominant-baseline` style will be ignored?

I have two `<text>` labels in two different parts of my SVG. The `dominant-baseline: central` applied to one works without issue (for example, when I open it up in Chrome's web inspector and change the value, the element moves around as I would expect it to), but it does not seem to affect the other (ex, changing the style's value from the web inspector doesn't change the position of the element).

Is there any reason this could be?

Here is a screenshot of the relevant code:

[image: code sample]

(I'll post a fiddle demonstrating the problem if I can figure out how to reproduce it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit was an errant `display: inline` that the `.label` was inheriting from its HTML counterpart.

The fix:

```
svg.label {
    display: block;
}
```